# Can't get Notepad++ to hit breakpoints using xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a problem trying to debug using xdebug, DBGp and Notepad++ as it never hits my breakpoints. I have done a lot of searching and cannot see where I am going wrong:

I have configured with the correct ports and when looking at my xdebug.log I can see that it seems to be happy:

```
Log opened at 2013-04-22 12:10:58
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8080.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/resources/appliance/download_agents.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2740" idekey="xdebug"><engine version="2.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2013-04-22 12:10:58

Log opened at 2013-04-22 12:11:19
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8080.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/resources/appliance/download_agents.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2740" idekey="xdebug"><engine version="2.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2013-04-22 12:11:19
```

However it never seems to hit the breakpoints.

I have set DBG breakpoint in file download_agents.php and I enter the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/download_agents.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=xdebug
```

but it never hits it. Refresh causes a new entry to be added to above mentioned log file so seems to connect. However the GUI for DBG within Notepad++ doesn't have a connected message on it.

My php.ini file entries are as follows:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\nginx\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_port=8080 
xdebug.remote_mode=req 
xdebug.idekey=default 
xdebug.remote_log="c:\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log" 
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0 
xdebug.show_local_vars=9 
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0 
xdebug.trace_format=0 
xdebug.profiler_enable  = 1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:\tmp\xdebug"
```

and the DBG config looks as follows:

[image]

Both the Remote Path and Local Path point to the root of my web app and match that of the output in the xdebug.log file:

file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/resources/appliance/download_agents.php"

Please any assistance would be greatly received..

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to define an ide-key? i.e. 'xdebug.idekey=myIDE0815' and 'IDE KEY => myIDE0815'

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have added an IDE key but this can be anything you like right? Doesn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that I changed the remote_port from 9000 to 8080 as this is the port my PHP is listening to...

Comment: Since your running win (dll), you could try TCP-View or Process-Monitor to see, if notepad is listening and if there is a connection. Did you use '?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name' before? BTW: Eclipse PHP-Plugin works well ;-)

Comment: Hi I wasn't aware of this tool but after using it I can see that my php-cgi.exe is running on Local Port 9000 and so is Notepad++. However nginx (my web server) is running on 8080 which is the port I am using to access the pages and as mentioned above the port I changed xdebug renote_port to. Any ideas? Thanks for your input :-)

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure, that you want two processes listening to the same port?! I think this cannot work. Why don't you leave it at 9000? Anyway, did you restart the server?

Comment: I think, you know this link: [link]http://thecancerus.com/debugging-php-using-xdebug-and-notepad-part-i/

Comment: Hmm. I might be getting somewhere now. Changing PHP to be on a different port causes Notepad++ to react to a page being served, BUT I get an error in Notepad++ stating: XML document must have a top level element. Line: 0. Any ideas? What port should I run PHP on I just choose 9001 instead? Thanks

Comment: I think you should keep default 9000.

XML error:
Is the a result of your php-code or npp-config?
Lino 0 of which file? (Filemon or Process-Monitor may help).

Comment: Maybe should update your title/question for better understanding.

Comment: Yes I think for now I need to confirm why I have two applications running on the same port and try and look into which file Notepad++ is referring to when stating that "XML document must have a top level element. Line: 0". Thanks for your help. Not sure how to set this question to, well inactive or something as its not solved and don't want people to waste their time looking at it without an appropriate solution. Thanks very much for your time, your input was greatly appreciated and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Applications: One is your server, the other was xdebug (until you set back to dafault). What you have to tell is, where you get that error-message or better how's throwing this message. If it's Notepad++ you may try an update / a clean install of Npp (just to be sure). Maybe, you can start DBGp in verbose-mode. Another try could be using filemon, hoping you find npp reading a xml.

Comment: Hi I am going to mark this as answered as I think that you have told me what I need to know and that is my configuration is incorrect. I will have to resolve this before trying to debug using notepad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. Again: You may also use i.e. eclipse: actual version, php-plugin, go ;-) Maybe you'll find more in the internet about that. If you like to spend some money, phpStorm is a real good juice - and payable. Good Luck!